# UISearchBar displayed on top of Overlay

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

My App has a `UITableView` with a `UISearchController` in the table view header.
Tapping on a table cell shows a dialog / overlay.  Overlay is a `UIVisualEffectView`.

**Issue:** The search bar is displaying over the overlay as shown.
[image]

I am setting `definesPresentationContext = true` on my view controller, and the code for setting up my UISearchController is the following...

```
lazy var resultSearchController: UISearchController = ({
  let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
  controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
  controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
  controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
  controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
  controller.searchBar.delegate = self
  return controller
})()
```

After setting `hidden` to false on the overlay.  I bring it to the front like so...

```
welcomeLabel.text = user!.fullName.isEmpty ? "Hello, \(user!.name)" : "Hello, \(user!.fullName)"
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(loginBackground)
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(loginContainer)
```

This issue arises only when the search bar is active.  Anyone know of a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried resignFirstResponder or setting editing to false?

Comment: I just tried those suggestions, but it unfortunately didn't fix things.  Thanks for the suggestion though.